# Coordinate System - South America - GWR4

Tags: coordinate-system, geographically-weighted-regression, brazil

I'm doing a regression in GWR4, and after selecting my X and Y coordinates / lat-long, I need to specify the spherical or projected option.

My data comes from QGis, which are in the EPSG 4674 SIRGAS 2000 geographic coordinate system.

Centroids were generated in GeoDa, and imported into GWR along with the data.

Basically they are cases of an injury in the State of Paraná, Brazil, with 5 independent variables for analysis.

In GWR, can I practically interpret SIRGAS 2000 as similar to WGS 84 and therefore select the "spherical" option to run the analysis? Because the only information I know about the system is: use "spherical" when WGS 84 and use "projected" when UTM, but in my case I am using the SIRGAS 2000 geographic coordinate system.

**Information about SIRGAS 2000 in QGIS:**
SIRGAS 2000
WKT
GEOGCRS["SIRGAS 2000",
DATUM["Sistema de Referencia Geocentrico para las AmericaS 2000",
ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
ORDER[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHMH8.png),
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
ORDER[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0eQq.png),
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
USAGE[
SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
AREA["Latin America - Central America and South America - onshore and offshore. Brazil - onshore and offshore."],
BBOX[-59.87,-122.19,32.72,-25.28]],
ID["EPSG",4674]]
Proj4
+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
Extensão
-122.19, -59.87, -25.28, 32.72

[image: GWR4 options]
[image: shapefile properti]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS.se! Although it's probably not directly relevant in this case, please consider Editing your question to include more information about the format of your data - QGIS is a program capable of working with many different data formats.